# how select viewResolver implicitly

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I use spring mvc

I have controller for rest web service

Sometimes I want to returns xml, Sometimes - json. In classPath I have and jackson and jaxb

How I can switch between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need ContentNegotiatingViewResolver. Please check [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html)
on the matter especially the **Returning multiple representations** section.